# PHP Upload File with date and time

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I am using this function to upload the file
How would I change the file name to: current date & time for example. As any user that uploads a file, it's uploaded to the users ID file but with the name of there actual file, rather than the current date and time. For example: 14/09/02/18:32

```html
<?php

    session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or empty($_SESSION["user"])) {
      // redirect to login page
}



$target_dir = ('users/'.$_SESSION["user"]["id"].'/');
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image


// Check if file already exists

// Check file size

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo header('Location: main.php');
    }
}
?>
```

:

Comment: You're already setting the name of the file, just append a string with the current date using PHP's `date()` function.

Comment: just goolge for php move_uploaded_file() when you don't know how this function works

Comment: @SARUAV a file cannot contain any of the following  \ / : * ? < > |"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try renaming your file before uploading it.

```
$target_dir = ('users/'.$_SESSION["user"]["id"].'/');
$removeExtension = explode('.',basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir .date("m-d-y").date("h-i-sa").".$removeExtension[1]"); //renamin the file to the current time as e.g. 02-03-15-01-13-18pm.jpg
$uploadOk = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with -

```
$name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$nameArr = explode('.', $name);
$ext = $nameArr[count($nameArr) - 1];
$newName = date('your-prefered-format').'.'.$ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `$target_file` variable. Note that slash is invalid in filename. For date see the date function in [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Better way is use the default img name and append date,

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

This is how a resulting path to a file is formed. To give a file a custom name, replace code after `$target_dir .` to something else to name your file.